# ubuntu non-root user set PS1 variable?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ps1

When I was a root user,I can change my PS1 varialble like this

[image]

but when I am not a root user,it seems strange for change PS1 variable.

[image]

so,why?

Comment: are you using a shell which supports the escape sequences when you are running as 'you'? Run `echo $0`.

Comment: the root user is '-bash',the non-root user is '-sh',haha,thank you,I solve this problem by set non-root user shell `usermod -s /bin/bash non-root-user`